# DataFrame.quantile() function didn't work when use apply function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I made a function to get the middle part of a DataFrame, but the quantile function didn't work well. So I can't get the part of dataframe I want.

I'm using pandas 0.23.4

Here is the func body.

```py
def func(df,key_name,tail):
    df_new = df[df[key_name]>df[key_name].quantile(tail)]
    return df_new
```

but it works good when I try it in this way

```
func(clean_video,'all_vv',0.1)
```

when I apply it like

```
clean_video.apply(func,axis = 1,args = ('all_vv',0.1))
```

I got the Error below.

```
AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'quantile'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: It is expected, because apply here working with each row separately.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.